# Show only item which haven't pass the deadline yet

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an item with the deadline. I want only show the item that haven't pass the deadline yet.

For instance, I set the first item's deadline to April 1st, 2016 at 8:00 and then create the second item with deadline March 1st, 2016 at 23:00.

Let's assume today is March 29th. So, the result will only show the first item.

Here is my current controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @items = Item.where(active: true, deadline: datetime < Time.today)
  end
end
```

Here is the `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "deadline"
  t.boolean "active"
end
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Do you want Time.now not Date.today? whats the format of your time_stamp?

Comment: @MikeK. thanks for replying. I update for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@items = Item.where('active = ? AND deadline > ?', true, Time.now)`

if you have joins:

`@items = Item.joins(:other_model).where('items.deadline > ?', Time.now)`

Comment: I made some changes to the question.